# TinyMCE - Customise CSS Styles Menu On Toolbar

Tags: css, menu, styles, tinymce

I have set up a simple CSS file with a single .test class and have the following settings in TinyMCE I get two menus that both say 'Paragraph at the top. How do edit the CSS styles menu

```
  tinymce.init({
        selector: '#tiny',
    menubar:false,
    'content_css': 'my-styles.css',
    importcss_append: false,
    style_formats_merge: true,
    plugins: ['importcss'],
toolbar: 'code| insertfile undo redo searchreplace | paste pastetext | formatselect | styleselect '
        });
```

format menu
[image: format menu]

css styles menu
[image: css styles menu]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example in case anyone else is looking:

```
content_style:
'.news-img-left { float: left;margin:1em 1em 1em 0;max-width:400px;height:auto }' +
'.news-img-right { float: right;margin:1em 0 1em 1em;max-width:400px;height:auto }' +
'.news-img-full { margin:1em 0;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto }',
style_formats: [
{ title: 'Text Formats' },
{ title: 'Paragraph', format: 'p' },
{ title: 'Heading 1', format: 'h1' },
{ title: 'Heading 2', format: 'h2' },
{ title: 'Heading 3', format: 'h3' },
{ title: 'Image Formats' },
{ title: 'Image Full Width', selector: 'img', classes: 'news-img-full' },
{ title: 'Image Left', selector: 'img', classes: 'news-img-left' },
{ title: 'Image Right', selector: 'img', classes: 'news-img-right' },
],
```

then in tool bar I added button 'styleselect'

Answer (score 0):

*This question was also asked in the [TinyMCE Github issuetracker](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/6143) and I'll copy in the answer here for completeness.*

Both formatselect and styleselect shows the currenly used [format](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting/#formats). The default format is the "Paragraph", matching the `<p>` tag basically.

The styleselect doesn't have anything to do with CSS style really, think of it more in terms of visual appearances. The differences between styleselect and formatselect are mainly in the config options available:

- The `formatselect` button is configured by the [block_formats option](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#block_formats) and is rather basic.
- The `styleselect` button is configured through the [style_formats option](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#style_formats) and is much more advanced. It can contain nested menus, have groups etc.